# Standing Waves Electric Field (how to create them)

Tags: visible-light

Question 1:how can we create a standing wave electric field?

Question 2: light is a form of electromagnetic radiation which and electric field and magnetic field component. is there any way we can use light to create standing wave electric field?

Comment: Look up how microwave ovens work :)

Comment: There is a standing wave of light inside a laser (between two mirrors).

Comment: Microwave ovens and optical cavity resonators (a.k.a., "lasers") contain electro-_magnetic_ waves. The only structure I know of that can contain something you might call an "electric wave" would be a [transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line).

Comment: Ah ok you want just the electric field and no magnetic field. Also, tag people in your comments so they know you replied :)

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38370/is-it-possible-to-create-only-a-magnetic-wave

Comment: Yes I want only the electric field